# @Autowiring and @Resource annotations in Spring

Tags: spring

My question is quick, we use @Autowire to wire beans by type, and @Resource by name, but I have always seen these annotations used to wire variables inside a class, can they be used at a classlevel as well to wire all the properties of a object?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see in the linked question the answer to which level these annotations apply to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question with the API of the annotations.

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD,METHOD})
public @interface Autowired

@Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface Resource
```

If you want to know when you can use the annotations go to the API and take special attention to the @Target values.

**ANNOTATION_TYPE**
Annotation type declaration

**CONSTRUCTOR**
Constructor declaration

**FIELD**
Field declaration (includes enum constants)

**LOCAL_VARIABLE**
Local variable declaration

**METHOD**
Method declaration

**PACKAGE**
Package declaration

**PARAMETER**
Parameter declaration

**TYPE**
Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

In general annotation only could be used in the places for which they are defined in the [@Target](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/Target.htm) values.

Comment: Ok, so then it is not possible to apply these annotations to the class itself, to wire all properties of a given object, that was my initial question. THanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just look at code or javadoc

- **Autowired**: ctor (but only one),  field, method, annotation

  @Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
- **Resource**: type, field, method

  @Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})